# How to remove this warning "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register."

Tags: redhat, yum, rhn

I get the following error when i am listing the updates.Server is currently registered with ULN. Although its a warning, i do not want the below message displayed when i am issuing yum command.i found out subscription-manager plugin is loaded. How to disable subscription-manager plugin??

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

Answer (score 50):

There are two possible solutions:

1. in the plugin configuration file, disable plugin:

```
    vim /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf
    
    enabled=0
```

2. Register to the satellite

Comment: does it work for RHEL 7.5 running on AWS ec2-instance as # subscription-manager register   --auto-attach
Registering to: subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription
Username: ashxxxxxx@abc.com
Password:
ashxxxxxx@abc.com cannot register with any organizations.

Comment: Setting enabled=0 took care of this for me in Fedora 33. File was /etc/dnf/plugins/subscription-manager.conf on my system.

Comment: For fresh installation of Fedora 32, the location of the configuration file is actually this:

`/etc/dnf/plugins/subscription-manager.conf`

Comment: Is there a command that can disable the plugin, as opposed to editing the file?

Comment: The flags `--noplugins` or `--disableplugin=plugin_name` can be used to disable from command line (via [red hat doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-yum_plugins)).

Comment: sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/'  /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf

Comment: register to satellite? expand please.

Answer (score 9):

At least in my case, RHEL 7.6, `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf` already had `enabled=0`.

`/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/enabled_repos_upload.conf` however, had `enabled=1`, and changing that to `enabled=0` prevented the warning.

Comment: This worked for me - although subscription-manager.conf had enabled=1, setting it to zero had no effect on the warning message.  enabled_repos_upload.conf enabled=0 suppressed the warning.

Answer (score 6):

To do this via the yum command line use `--disableplugin subscription-manager`.  This method is good for scripting.

The following example will not print "not registered" message:

```
# yum --disableplugin subscription-manager list installed | head -3
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos
Installed Packages
GConf2.x86_64                         3.2.6-8.el7                @anaconda/7.5
```

And just to show you that not providing the flag will print the "not registered" message:

```
# yum  list installed | head -5
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Installed Packages
GConf2.x86_64                         3.2.6-8.el7                @anaconda/7.5
```

Comment: This is much better than hand-jamming a config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For me, this was fixed after removing the subscription-manager:

```
sudo dnf remove subscription-manager
```

You can always re-install if necessary

Comment: This is the red hat recommended solution.

Comment: just noting that removing subscription-manager will trigger removal of other packages, which you might want (podman, ovirt, cockpit).

Comment: Even with this, I still get these message when running `dnf` commands:
Failed loading plugin "upload-profile": No module named 'subscription_manager'
Failed loading plugin "subscription-manager": No module named 'subscription_manager'
Failed loading plugin "product-id": No module named 'subscription_manager'

Answer (score 2):

Disable/remove the subscription-manager yum plugin.

Check this link: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/repos-disable

Comment: Florin, Will removing subscription-manager rpm resolve the issue as well?

Comment: Probably yes :).

Comment: link is not working   Page Not Found

Comment: Please update the link.

Comment: Removing subscription-manager wanted to autoremove ovirt and cockpit, so not a good option in my case.

Comment: This does not disable or remove the subscription-manager plugin.  This just disables the repos.  You will still get the "not registered" message.

Answer (score 1):

A few years have passed, yum has been replaced by dnf (but they seem to have made sure that command line parsing hasn't been broken too badly).

FWIW, dnf still produces the same error message, but it can be told to omit them with the `--quiet` switch. Chances aren't bad that this also works for yum.