# How to remove warning about "System not registered - please register to enable updates and addons" on Red Hat 8?

Tags: redhat, rhel8

I'm using a RHEL 8.2 system and don't wish to register the system, but I do want to stop getting this annoying notification. Similar to [this question asked several years ago,](https://serverfault.com/questions/764900/how-to-remove-this-warning-this-system-is-not-registered-to-red-hat-subscriptio) except that while the accepted solution works on my rhel7.6 builds, it doesn't work on the rhel8.2 builds. Also tried have been the similar suggestion in /etc/dnf/plugins/subscription-manager.conf, which doesn't work either, and the /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/enabled_repos_upload.conf file doesn't exist on my system.

Any ideas on this updated for Red Hat 8?

Answer (score 1):

as per [redhat support](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5637881):

> Red Hat does not endorse disabling the "System Not Registered" notification.
>
> Modify the GNOME Settings Daemon subscription manager plugin startup file.
>
> ```
> $ /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Subscription.desktop
> [Desktop Entry]
> Type=Application
> Name=GNOME Settings Daemon's subscription manager plugin
> Exec=/usr/libexec/gsd-subman
> OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
> NoDisplay=true
> X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
> X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
> X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=false
> X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false
> ```
>
> Reboot the system.